# Routing traffic in ubuntu from lan through tun-interface

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, routing

I'm trying to route some traffic by ip from my local LAN through a Ubuntu Server instance running openconnect to a remote server.

```
     Client             Router      Ubuntu Server (ens160)  tun0   remote resource
| 192.168.1.x | -> | 192.168.1.1 | -> | 192.168.1.38 | -> | VPN | -> | 1.1.1.1 |
```

**My routes looks like this :**

```
Destination    Gateway     Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0         U     0      0      0    tun0
1.3.4.0        0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     0      0      0    tun0   (vpn dhcp range)
1.4.5.6        192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0      0    ens160 (ip from remote)
192.168.1.0    0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     0      0      0    ens160
192.168.122.0  0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     0      0      0    virbr0
```

I have managed to route traffic headed for 1.1.1.1 to my Ubuntu server at `192.168.1.38`. A trace-route from the client verifies this.

```
Tracing route to [1.1.1.1] over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.38
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

So the traffic stops at the Ubuntu Server on the `ens160` interface (I presume). This is where I'm lost. I have searched for solutions, but I'm a bit confused with the multitude of options I have here. Originally I just wanted to add a static route saying `src lan through tun0`, but the gateway is `0.0.0.0`? I then see the third route is an ip belonging to the remote vpn-location. So I presume this is a route out through my WAN for the VPN.

I have enabled ip forwarding. And tried adding a masquarade and nat rule with iptables. But I'm sure I messed this up somehow.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE  
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens160 -j ACCEPT
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to enable forwarding in the kernel. Run:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
or
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

see if it works.

Add  `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `/etc/sysctl.d/80-forward.conf` (or something like that) to survive after reboot.

**Edit**

Maybe you forgot to allow the traffic go back in FORWARD chain. Try this:

```
# iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

So the traffic can go back.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, but forwarding is enabled.

Comment: @iNzzane Maybe you need to let traffic come back from `tun0` (See my edit).

Comment: -P INPUT ACCEPT

-P FORWARD ACCEPT

-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT Still nothing. Traceroute stops at the host.